# Unknown type specified in package.xml

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, package.xml

I have the following package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
<members>clock/clock.html</members>
<members>clock/clock.css</members>
<members>clock/clock.js</members>
<members>clock/clock.js-meta.xml</members>
<name>LightningComponentResource</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>clock</members>
<name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
<version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```

When I attempt to deploy these changes along with LWC, I get:

```
Unknown type name 'LightningComponentResource' specified in package.xml.
```

I have checked the API version on destination org and it is 53.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

To Deploy or Retrieve the LWC component. LightningComponentBundle type is sufficient in package.xml

```
<types>
<members>clock</members>
<name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
```

Try removing the `LightningComponentResource` and they deploy it.